# If $|A| = |B| = 5$, how many functions $f: A \to B$ are invertible?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

> Assuming $|A| = |B| = 5$, how many functions $$f: A \to B$$ are invertible?

I'm a bit lost on how to start this problem, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "invertible" means the same thing as "bijective".

Comment: Invertible = bijective... how many bijections from 5 points to 5 points? And remember that bijective means that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \iff x_1=x_2$

Comment: There are five!!

Comment: (note the punctuation)

Comment: Suppose A = {1,2,3,4,5} and B = {a, b, c, d, e}.  What can f(1) = equal?  If f(1) = *whatever* then what can f(2) equal?

Comment: @Unit That's not correct - there are many more than that. For instance, there are already six bijections from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ to $\{1, 2, 3\}$ . . . EDIT: **grrrrr . . .** :P

Comment: @NoahSchweber Unit may have been making a joke with the exclamation points.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I realized that once his second comment popped up. I decided to leave my comment up (with an edit) for comedic value. (I could have also gone the scifi route: "There! Are! Five!! Maps!")

Comment: I missed his second comment.  "There! Are! Five!! Maps!"  (that is funny!)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  A bijection maps the first element to something.  How many possibilities are there?  Once you choose where the first element maps to, how many possibilities are there to map the second element to?  The third?  The fourth?  The fifth?

How many choices total are there?

Comment: So this is a counting question? 5! ?

Comment: Seems that way to me.  Unless I am missing something.  But doesn't that make sense?  A mapping between sets of 5 elements, when you get down to it and don't get distracted by all that functiony analysis stuff, is simply a way of putting five elements into five places.  There are $5^5$ functions total.  If the function is bijective each placing is unique and there are $5!$ possibilities.  Right?

Comment: Yeah makes sense. Took me a bit of time to wrap my head around it.

Comment: We get so used to infinite functions that where we discrete math is utterly irrelevant, that we don't realize that finite functions are really an entirely different animal.  But they do give you a chance to really get you hands dirty that functions are *mappings*; not rules.